# Determine Case owner is queue or user?

Tags: case, polymorphism, validation-rule

how to check whether a case owner is a queue or a user?  I am writing a validation rule where i need to check who is the owner of the case.

Answer (score 12):

You can check if any of the User- or Queue-specific polymorphic Owner fields is empty. 
e.g.

```
ISBLANK(Owner:Queue.Id)
```

will be true if the owner is a User and false if the owner is a Queue

The opposite would be:

```
ISBLANK(Owner:User.Id)
```

More info about polymorphic fields here:
https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2013/06/cross-object-owner-fields-a-powerful-new-formula-option.html

Answer (score 9):

A tip to @guy as I didn't know about the polymorphic formulas (sheesh)

Another solution is

```
LEFT(OwnerId,3) = '00G'  /* this is a queue, all Queue Sobject ids start with 00G */
```