# Need assistance with Case Owner validation rule

Tags: case, validation-rule

Trying to wrap my head around a validation rule and could use a push in the right direction.

Scenario:

Case is escalated to a Queue.  The manager reviews the complaint and if necessary, changes the Status to "Reviewed and Assigned to CSR".  The change of ownership will need to be done from a Queue to a CSR manually, but I would like a VR that forces them to change the owner to a user and not a queue when the status is changed. This prevents them from changing the status but not changing the owner so that it doesn't sit in the queue not being worked.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I guess you just need to determine that the field value is set to a user and not to a queue, this question has the answer http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/53582/determine-case-owner-is-queue-or-user

Comment: Use ISCHANGED function to check if old and new values are different. Rest stuffs are quite simple. I think you already have an answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, I tested it in my dev org (with a different status value) and it worked fine

```
AND(
    ISCHANGED(Status),
    ISPICKVAL(Status, "Reviewed and Assigned to CSR"),
    ISBLANK(Owner:User.Id)
)
```